# Get region_prefix to work with redisson-hibernate-53 L2 cache

Tags: hibernate, caching, redis, redisson

I am trying to configure Redis as Hibernate's L2 cache for Spring boot app using Redisson (Spring 2.3.0, Hibernate 5.4.15, redisson-hibernate-53).

The application YAML has this section under spring.jpa.properties.hibernate

```
        cache:
          use_second_level_cache: true
          region.factory_class: org.redisson.hibernate.RedissonRegionFactory
          region_prefix: app1
          redisson:
            config: redisson.yaml
            fallback: true
```

Everything works except the region_prefix.
The response from running `KEYS *`  in redis-cli shows that the main key is the fully qualified class name of my Cacheable entity but it does not have the region prefix.
I cannot see any reference in the `RedissonRegionFactory` and related code to Hibernate's `RegionNameQualifier`.

Has anyone got this working or is it a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get it to work. I opened an issue and they fixed it immediately. It will be released with `Redisson 3.13.7`. Redission ignored the cache region prefix.

see [issue](https://github.com/redisson/redisson/issues/3207)